# visualstudio.com, forget account, use Microsoft account

Tags: visual-studio

I try to go to a Visualstudio.com project that I was invited to. Every time I try, it tells me that my **other, completely irrelevant address** is not allowed to access there. Where do I input the address I want to use? It is my Microsoft.com account and the one I have as my user account in Visual Studio.

In other words it gives me:

*NOT AUTHORIZED
Sorry, but Arto Kilponen (and then the address info here) is not authorized to access this page
Sign out and connect with another login

Service Status and Support @VSTeam
More information about this error
TF400813: The user 'theotheruser address' is not authorized to access this resource.*

so where's the "use my Microsoft.com account instead"-link? Signing out and signing back in didn't solve this.

Comment: You've probably checked a "Remember me" or "Keep me logged in" checkbox somewhere. You can go here to [sign out](https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_signout) and try signing in again. Or you could try an Incognito window. What happens when you sign out from Visual Studio? (maybe you checked the remember thing there)

Comment: Clear the browser cache and then try again.

Comment: Pretty good ideas (and I think I should have known to use them before asking), but no, neither incognito nor clear cache (let alone trying another browser) worked. For some reason, as soon as I enter my email address and navigate out of the field, by, say, pressing tab or clicking the password box, I'm redirected to elsewhere, where it asks me to log in to this current account. And yes, this is **before** inputting the password, so it definitely can't be that my password would be incorrect - since it doesn't even want it, just redirects me.

Comment: Oh, and the same "input username and we'll throw you elsewhere" occurs when logging into Visual Studio (that is, obviously logged out first).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I needed visualstudio.com to forget my email address. I can confirm that clearing browser data is not enough (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData), but I have just resolved it by removing all cookies and site data from chrome settings here chrome://settings/content/cookies and click REMOVE on these two cookies "YOUR-REPO.pkgs.visualstudio.com" and "YOUR-REPO.vssps.visualstudio.com". After this visualstudio.com prompts for email and password again instead of remembering another unrelated email address.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.